# Setting background color in xhtml2pdf

Tags: pisa, xhtml2pdf

I have a problem with setting background-color using xhtml2pdf library.
I want to create specific size element and I do it with success by @frame keyword like this:

```
@frame r1c1_frame { 
    left: 35pt; width: 262pt; top: 35pt; height: 150pt;
}
@frame r1c2_frame {
    left: 297pt; width: 262pt; top: 35pt; height: 150pt;
}
```

and if I put -pdf-frame-border: 1; I can see border with specific size. 
Problem is with the background color for that frame, I can not set color in any way.
I set css calss:

```
.blok {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: white;
    background-color: #ac4121;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5pt;
    display: block;
}
```

and use it for div tag and no success.

Did You have any similar issue?

Thank You.

Answer (score -4):

Try to put `background: #ac4121` instead of `background-color: #ac4121`, in some elements works.